# FileNotFoundEXception in android zxing library

Tags: android, zxing

I am using `zxing2.0` library for `android` but I get this exception :, what does it mean ?

```
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{phoenix.metro.uis/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/xml/preferences.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f050000
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/xml/preferences.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f050000
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:860)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager.buildMediaPlayer(BeepManager.java:97)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager.updatePrefs(BeepManager.java:60)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager.<init>(BeepManager.java:49)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:165)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 11 more
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:427)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:857)
10-01 22:20:03.197: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 17 more
```

Comment: It sounds like you copied our code and changed it, and didn't change the resource references. Your copy refers to stuff you deleted. It's not a problem in the library or app. In fact it's better if you don't start from a copy of our app.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem! I fix it by a step-by-step guide in which writer explains very well how to implement a barcode reader/encoder using zxing library. The difference from original manual is that he seems to use his version of library, modified in some point (as he shows in the article) that fixes the problem. Follow his instructions and download his zxing library. It works for me:

[michalu zxing barcode](http://michalu.eu/wordpress/scanning-and-generating-barcodes-using-zxing-library-on-android/)

Comment: Edited trying to give a summary explanation